# iTextSharp error, casting IncCell to Rectangle

Tags: itext

I've been asked to look at C# code that's returning the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type
'iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.IncCell' to type 'iTextSharp.text.Rectangle'.
  at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.Add(IElement element)
  at iTextSharp.text.Document.Add(IElement element)
```

It looks like they're using iTextSharp v5.0.2 and have not yet moved from HtmlWorker to XmlWorker.

Questions:

1. What is IncCell? I see it in the source docs but can't find any info about what it is - I'm assuming it's just for internal use.
2. Is this related to a cell in a table? A need for a Div or Paragraph within a cell?
3. What can they do to diagnose issues like this down to the HTML source that caused the error? I suspect this is an issue with not conforming to XHTML, but I can't verify that without knowing exactly what IElement that code was working on when it choked. It could be due to bad styling too, I have no idea at this time. Is there any kind of detail logging that will tell us what element is being processed at any given time? Should I just get them to load source and trace through it?
4. Is it probable that this will be fixed with an update to the latest version (currently 5.5.9), and a re-fit of XmlWorker?
5. Other recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to update anyway, don't update to `5.0.8` but to `5.5.9`. If you suspect issues with malformatted XHTML, it's not a bad idea to parse with some kind of HTML cleanup tool. In the Java world I know HTML Tidy and Jsoup, I don't know the equivalents in the .NET world. Realistically, don't expect any interesting answers about `HTMLWorker` because that has been deprecated for several years. I suggest that you just try it with `XMLWorker`, and if you still have issues, open a new question.

Comment: I brain farted on that 5.0.8 and modified the question. Thanks for that! I agree on the cleanup and on XMLWorker. The thing is that I've been asked to identify the possible sources of the problem. The user management is asking why this error didn't occur before and why it wasn't in QA. I can't tell them yet if their developer made a change which broke the code, or if some new CSS did it, or if user data has embedded reserved characters, etc. So while the changes recommended are entirely valid, I'd still like to understand how to properly diagnose this kind of issue.

Comment: Are they iText customers and do they have a support contract?

Comment: As I was looking into the code it was apparent that there could be a licensing issue - I didn't see any code to load a license key but it's possible that I'm just not aware of some details. I immediately emailed management and recommended proper licensing. So an inquiry is open on that as well as this technical issue. At this time it would be inappropriate to make a formal support request, especially without more detail from their side.

Comment: Issue was due to malformed XML. A table was started but not properly terminated. But without attempting to get free support from the good folks at iText, I'm wondering if someone else can help to answer the original questions about HOW we approach debugging issues like this. I am recommending that the client get a license for the software to help with situations like this.

Comment: Well if your client doesn't want to pay for a support contract, then your best possible option is community support here on StackOverflow, which involves sharing your code and your XHTML, and then hoping that there is a good soul who wants to help you out in exchange for some SO reputation. Fortunately we are very nice people at iText Software, and we often nudge the free users in the right direction so they can find a solution themselves. But obviously without any guarantees, it's all best effort and in spare time.

Comment: Yes, which is why I posted in SO (not being paid by the client for my time, in the interest of sharing info with fellow users) rather than telling the client they need to go to iText first. So I'm not looking for a solution to the problem. I did the research and found and fix it. I'm asking in a general sense what we can do to diagnose these issues on our own. Please feel free to decline a specific response, your position is certainly understood. But thanks for your time here in any case.

Comment: In case of issues with XMLWorker, it's very often malformed XHTML, so one of the first things to do is to run it through the W3C Validator. If any errors come up, fix those first before you continue. In the Java world I know about Tidy an JSoup who can clean up XHTML, I am sure that equivalent things exist in the .NET world. Run your XHTML through one of those parsers before you feed it to iTextSharp and you will have a lot less headache.

Comment: I see that I already mentioned that. :D

Comment: That's fair. If you re-post your comment "In case of issues.." as an Answer, I will give you proper credit and close this item. Thanks for your patience.